# How can I add integrate a React app into an existing asp.net core application?

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, mern

I've written a small app with MERN stack, and a software company have asked if they can integrate it as a module in their ASP.NET Core / SQL Server application they offer to engineering companies. Will this be a simple procedure or is it going to work out quicker and easier to rebuild it with ReactJS.net and then add it to their solution?